# How to show and add categories of products in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR and currently practicing with rails 3.2. I am working on developing an app that for example lists all products but allows users upon signing up to filter and see only the products they like.

I've searched under categories and filters but not quite sure what I'm looking for and what the best way to go about it is.  A little guidance would be appreciated.

Are there any tutorials/railscasts available that have this feature?

Comment: The question is very broad. You will get lot of tutorials for RoR if you search in google. Try to write some code yourself and if you are stuck then post the code here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment & I will do this but I'm stuck as far as where to start.  My question is how do I list different products that have images & belong to a certain category? I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use `gem 'cancan'` for authorizations. You can allow the users to see the products they like.

You can give conditional checking for different types of users also.

The git repository [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Also see the [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) for use of cancan

Comment: I already have authorization, but what I'm asking is how to list different products with their images that belong to different categories...

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of SQL you should join `products` and `likes`.
Thus your query will looks like:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN likes ON product.id = likes.product_id
WHERE likes.user_id = <current_user.id>
```

Shifting it to the Rails (there is [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) and [where](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)) you query will looks like:

```
Product.joins('INNER JOIN likes ON product.id = likes.product_id').
        where('likes.user_id = ?', current_user.id)
```

I suppose to think you have relations between `products` and `likes`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

You can simplify your `join` and query will looks like:

```
Product.joins(:likes).where('likes.user_id = ?', current_user.id)
```